# short if then else statements trouble

Tags: c#

Hello I would like to shorten the code I write below. Can you help me?

```
IstSAF = 
    Convert.ToInt32(sD.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Decode == "IstSAF")?.Value) == 0 
        ? 1 
        : Convert.ToInt32(sD.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Decode == "IstSAF")?.Value);
```

Thank you

Edit:

Thanks for the replies. But I forgot to tell you that the code is inside an initialization of a class which in turn is inside a LINQ query.

```
IEnumerable<T>types = 
  From t in someTypes
  select new T()
  {
    IstSAF = 
      Convert.ToInt32(t.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Decode == "IstSAF")?.Valore) == 0 
          ? 1 
          : Convert.ToInt32(t.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Decode == "IstSAF")?.Valore),
  }
```

Comment: Don't write such code in the first place. You gain nothing by stuffing everything into a single, long, unreadable line

Comment: Just place this into a local variable and reuse it: `Convert.ToInt32(sD.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Decode == "IstSAF")?.Value)`

Comment: What does `sD.FirstOrDefault` return? string? Integer? Object? You can use `int.TryParse` to parse strings and return the result. You wouldn't need to convert anything though, or use `.Value` if the value is an `int?`

Comment: Doesn't your code throw if there is no item with `Decode=="istSAF"`?

Comment: A `switch` expression could help if you get an `int?` *really* want to convert 0 to 1, eg `switch sD.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Decode == "IstSAF") { case null =>0, case 0=>1,var i=>i}`

Comment: This code doesn't work in the first place. `Convert.ToInt32` doesn't return an `int?` so `?.Value` will throw a compilation error. The correct code *depends on the result type* of `FirstOrDefault`. Is it a string? An `int?`.

Comment: you can declare variables in LINQ queries, use `let`.

Comment: For the new requirement, just use @Kjartan code, make it a function, call it, and get the result

Comment: What is stopping you to use `foreach()/for()` loop instead of linq. Instead of `Select()`, you just need to wrap below logic inside foreach loop that;s all

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen
Thanks for the reply
in the class initialization there are many properties of that type so I should set many lets

Answer (score 4):

Just extract the messy part:

```
var myValue = Convert.ToInt32(sD.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Decode == "IstSAF")?.Value);

int IstSAF = myValue?.Value == 0 ? 1 : myValue?.Value;
```

...alternatively, for extra safety, use `TryParse()` and handle the result in some appropriate way:

```
int myValue;
bool isValid = int.TryParse(sD.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Decode == "IstSAF")?.Value, 
                            out myValue);

if(isValid)
{
    IstSAF = myValue.Value == 0 ? 1 : myValue.Value;
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("IstSAF was not a valid int value");
}
```

Comment: Yes, the concept is that, but if you notice, the OP code tries to conver the Value not the whole object returned by FirstOrDefault

Comment: @Steve the OP's code is weird to begin with. `Convert.ToInt3` doesn't return `int?`, so what's the point of `?.Value`? If the value is really an `int?`, no conversion is needed

Comment: OK that comes after, but x.Decode == "IstSaf" is a check for a property of an object of some type. FirstOrDefault will return that object if found. What are we trying to convert or parse here?

Comment: @Steve an object with a `Value` property? That's the only way this code could compile

Comment: Yes the OP code is more or less correct, not this one

Comment: You're right, I accidentally dropped the `Value` part. Updated my code.

Comment: Better now, but still with a problem. If FirstOrDefault doesn't find a match then the code tries to access a null.Value

Comment: @Steve I saw it, just added that too... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `int.TryParse()`

```
var myValue = sD.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Decode == "IstSAF")?.Value;
if(int.TryParse(myValue, out int IstSAF))
    IstSAF = IstSAF == 0 ? 1 : IstSAF;
```

---

As per your latest update:

If this is inside Linq `Select()`, then I would prefer to write `foreach` loop.

```
List<int> result = new List<int>();
foreach(var t in someTypes)
{
   //Logic to parse value to int
   var myValue = t.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Decode == "IstSAF")?.Value;
   if(int.TryParse(myValue, out int IstSAF))
       IstSAF = IstSAF == 0 ? 1 : IstSAF;

   result.Add(IstSAF); //Store int value.
}

//Print if you want
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result);
```

Comment: I am still thinking can we use `??=` operator to minimize `IstSAF = IstSAF == 0 ? 1 : IstSAF;`. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable in a Linq query:

```
    IEnumerable<T> types =
                from t in someTypes
                let valore = Convert.ToInt32(t.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Decode == "IstSAF")?.Valore)
                select new T()
                {
                    IstSAF = valore == 0 ? 1 : valore,
                };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply in the class initialization there are many properties of that type so I should set many lets